# Is it okay to only use username/password to secure an admin page for moderating a website?

Tags: authentication, web-application, linux, webserver, authorization

Is there a standard practice to securing an admin page for an application written in angular and nodejs or just in general? The admin page would approve/ban users and moderate comments.

Should it be web facing, able to be accessed just through a username/password? Or something fancy like ssh-only w/ X11 forwarding?

Right now I'm the only admin since I wrote the software, but I may eventually allow others to help moderate using their own combination of username/password. This might mean that non-tech users may be using it, so ssh-only might be too complex.

Is there something specific server-wise I should do for the admin page? I will deploy to a linux server (Ubuntu server).

Comment: Don't forget to add account louckout policy.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is fine to have a web facing panel as long as:

1. Its not guessable, for example, **www.example.com/admin**. U don't want notorious users to attempt brute-forcing for two reasons:

   - Incase the brute-force succeeds.
   - If u have an account lockout policy in place, which you should, u don't want to be locked out by notorious users.
2. Use **strong passwords** which are not going to be standard dictionary passwords.
3. Use **out-of-band authentication** along with the regular authentication system. This prevents brute-force as well as account-lockouts.
4. **Restrict the admin-panel to specific ip addresses** such as ur internal subnet address and only accessible through VPN, this should give u one extra layer of protection.
   More on this at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2851584/4399898.
5. And **HTTPS should be the standard**, if the cookie doesn't have the secure flag and HTTP-only property set and the admin browses to a page after logging in and not signing out and this page contains a malicious injected script, a là XSS, it can lead to the cookie being stolen and probably the authentication being effectively rendered useless along with CSRF bypass attacks etc. So, IMO, HTTPS should be implemented throughout the application.
6. If there are multiple admins and the authentication system has a **SQL db backend**, use **parameterised queries**.

Thats all i can think of right now. The link i posted with my fourth point should give u more information.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of applications relies on a simple username/password combination. This is not the technique that you should worry about, but how you implement it.

You need to make sure that passwords are strong enough not to be guessed. They should not be stored in plain-text in your database in case it gets compromised. Furthermore, you want to avoid interception of the password (or hashes) by having a configured HTTPS login page.

Other password recommendation applies (don't reuse password, etc...)

If you are really worried about the method, you can add more/use other ways to authenticate users (use of 2-factors authentication, openid, ...)

Answer (score 0):

For low value sites, username and password is ok. There are a lot of sites that are just not worth hacking into, and where the risk/cost of compromise to you is fairly minimal compared to the cost of securing it.

For most sites though, you should require the use of HTTPS or VPN when doing administrative functions. There are now some SSL certificate authorities that provide basic domain-validated certificate for free that are trusted by all major browsers, so there's really no excuse not to use SSL when you need the security.

For high value sites, in addition to encrypting the communication, you should also require multi-factor authentication. You may want to require client certificate or a one-time password or a hardware token. This increases the difficulty of administration, but that is a reflection of how much you care about security.

It's always a balance between security and usability.